# JSF Command button refreshes the page whenever its pressed

Tags: javascript, jsf, commandbutton

I have a simple jsf form with a button that is supposed to trigger a method call on the backing bean

```
<h:form id="form">
    <h:commandButton id="button" value="Submit" action="#{controller.submit}"
             onComplete="promptSuccess('Changes submitted successfully')" />
</h:form>
```

Everytime I press that button, the page refreshes and the JavaScript function 'promptSuccess' never even gets called.

I would like the form to be updated and also the success function be called as soon as the changes have been submitted. But the whole page gets refreshed.

I did see a few examples on SO but none of them proved useful to my particular problem/situation.

I would really appreciate some help on this.

Examples referred to:

[Example_1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8988780/how-make-commandbutton-not-fully-refresh-page-how-to-use-fajax)

[Example_2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36498908/pcommandbutton-refreshes-entire-page-instead-of-partially-whereas-fajax-works)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Execute JavaScript before and after the f:ajax listener is invoked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24912335/execute-javascript-before-and-after-the-fajax-listener-is-invoked)

Comment: You **should** use ajax like in the first example you posted and then read the duplicate